# Semi-direct product of different groups make a same group?

Tags: group-theory

We can prove that both of:

> $S_3=\mathbb Z_3\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_6=\mathbb Z_3\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$

So two different groups (and not isomorphic in examples above) can be described as semi-direct products of a pair of groups ($\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_2$). I hope my question does make sense:

> Is there any group which can be described as semi-direct products of two different pair of groups?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? (I assume this isn't homework, but I still think questions like this make valuable self-imposed exercises and it is not clear to me that asking them on math.SE is the most productive thing to do before doing some work on them.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for what you noted me. I got more from them. Actually, I didn't know how to ask this kind of question here. I'll try to do what you said. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a non-trivial example the comes up in practice:

Whenever $p$ is a prime number, there are two non-abelian groups of order $p^3$:

- the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ acting as $\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\. & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and
- the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ acting as $x\mapsto x^{1+p}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$.

However, when $p=2$ the unthinkable happens: the two groups are both isomorphic to the dihedral group of order 8!

The “dihedral” aspect of the group is mostly the second semi-direct product, with the reflections acting on the group of rotations. However the first is very important as the Sylow 2-subgroup of the simple group GL(3,2) of order 168.

When $p$ is an odd prime, the two groups are very different. The first has exponent $p$ (all elements have order $p$) while the second visibly has an element of order $p^2$.

This sort of behavior is not too uncommon in *p*-groups of larger order and is one difficulty in “naming” them, even the ones who look like they should have names.

<sub>(The other examples given apply equally well as “counterexamples” to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: $16 = 2 \times 8 = 4 \times 4$, $12 = 4 \times 3 = 6 \times 2$, or even $4=1\times 4 = 2 \times 2$. The example given here is not of this form, as $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a non-trivial semi-direct product.)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

For one example, we have $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$, since direct products are a case of semi direct products with trivial action.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Take $G = C_2^4$, which is the direct product of $C_2$ and $C_2^3$ but also the direct product of $C_2^2$ and $C_2^2$. An even less interesting example is $G = C_2^2$, which is the direct product of $1$ and $C_2^2$ but also the direct product of $C_2$ and $C_2$. I assume you wanted more "interesting" examples, though.

Answer (score 3):

*Such a group of smallest order is $D_8$, the Dihedral group of order 8.*

Write $D_8=\langle x,y\colon x^4=y^2=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle=\{1,x,x^2,x^3, y,xy,x^2y,x^3y \}$.

1. $H=\langle x\rangle$,$K=\langle y\rangle$, then $D_8=H\rtimes K\cong C_4\rtimes C_2$.
2. $H=\langle x^2,y\rangle$, $K=\langle xy\rangle$, then $D_8=H\rtimes K\cong (C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: Only if you don't allow direct products to be semidirect products!

Comment: of course! for abelian groups, its easy to find examples;  $C_3\timec C_2\cong C_6\times C_1$!!!